# Delete statement not remove the record

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using pdo and I'm trying to remove the records that have a date (expire) less than the current. Actually I made a little pdo wrapper that bind the value automatically this is the statement:

```
DELETE FROM auth_tokens WHERE expires < :currentTime;"
```

I pass to the delete function the table name, the wehre clause and the params to bindin, in particular:

```
public function delete($table, $where, $bind = "")
{
    $sql = "DELETE FROM " . $table . " WHERE " . $where . ";";
    $this->run($sql, $bind);
}
```

the run function will bind the data and execute the statement as:

```
binding result: [":currentTime"]=> string(27) "09-12-2016 21:21:56.7358640"
```

the problem's that no record is deleted. How you can see I'm trying to delete all the records that have an expire less than current time: 09-12-2016 21:21:56.7358640

why?

Comment: I hope you don't store dates in string format in the database. That could be a problem.

Comment: You have to convert your date as string to a real date obj

Comment: my date in the db are in datetime format

Comment: I would use `WHERE expires < NOW()` instead of passing in a time

Comment: Or to add to what bassxzero said, if you want to delete stuff older than 30, you can do that in SQL as well: `WHERE expires < SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)`

Comment: if I change I remove two equal date, so instead putting the < I insert the = the delete will work, so could be a query problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the standard `DATETIME` data type, then your date appears to be incorrectly formatted. Try formatting it like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.